# recurrence relation of general difference polynomials

Tags: recurrence-relations, maple

I have a sequence of difference polynomials (which I obtained by the method of finite differences) and I would like to find out if there is a recurrence relation between them.

The generating function of general difference polynomials is given by:

[gen func](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Difference_polynomials)

How would one write the above using maple and is there a way to find out in maple if there exists a recurrence relation between those polynomials?